# Show categories side-by-side using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to list categories and subcategories side-by-side using Codeigniter. just like here: http://prntscr.com/mtj2ov

```
for example:
Flowers 
Flowers -> Rose
Flowers -> Tulips
Flowers -> Lilies
```

### Table

```
id - subid - category_name - category_description - status
 1     0          Flowers            -                 1
 2     1          Rose               -                 1
 3     1          Tulips             -                 1
```

### This model content

```
public function getCategoryTree($id=0, $sub_mark=''){
    $rows = $this->db->select('*')->where('subid', $id)->order_by('id','asc')->get('ci_category')->result();
    $category = ''; 
    if (count($rows) > 0) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $category .= '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$sub_mark.$row->category_name.'</option>';
            $category .= $this->getCategoryTree($row->id, $sub_mark.'--');
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
    return $category;
}
```

### This Control content

```
$data['all_categroy'] = $this->category_model->get_all_category();
```

as with the example, how I need to make a change in the model and control file

Comment: whats your table structure?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra above, i wrote ;)

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: @M.Hemant I'm getting output as selectbox now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this,**

```
$result = $this->db->select('*')->order_by('id','asc')->get('ci_category')->result();
$parentName = '';
$select = "<select>";
foreach ($result as $r) {
    if ($r->subid == 0) {
        $select.= "<option id='" . $r->id . "' >" . $r->category_name . "</option>";
        $parentName = $r->c_name . ' --> ';
    } else {
        $select.= "<option id='" . $r->id . "' >" . $parentName . $r->category_name . "</option>";
    }
}
$select.= "</select>";
echo $select;
die;
```

Comment: adding some explanation also help for future visitors :)

Comment: sure sir,will looking for it now, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try to Generate SEO Friendly URL

follow these conditions:

https://www.codexworld.com/generate-seo-friendly-url-codeigniter/