# save value null to database using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

> Error Message
> A Database Error Occurred
> Error Number: 1366
>
> Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'parent_id' at row 1
>
> INSERT INTO cli_request_type (request_type, parent_id, created_on, created_by) VALUES ('Software', '', '2019-03-13 10:35:54', 1)
>
> Filename: C:/Xamppi/htdocs/clihelpdesk/bonfire/core/BF_Model.php
>
> Line Number: 482

I have a problem working on codeIgniter, the case is when I want to create parent with parent_id = null, which can save to the database can only be one parent, and when I want to create the next parent with parent_id null, but always raises error notifications like this integer value: '' for column 'parent_id' at row 1 ".
how can I make more parents not just one?

[I want to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeiBs.png)

view code

```
<div class="control-group">
<?php
    $options = array();
    $result = $this->db->count_all_results('request_type');
    if ($result > 0) 
    {
        echo form_dropdown('parent_id', dd2menu('request_type', array('id' => 'request_type')), $options, set_value('parent_id', isset($request_type->request_type) ? $request_type->request_type : 'Parent Id*'));
    }
    else 
    {
        echo form_dropdown('name', dd2menu('request_type', array('id' => 'request_type')), $options, set_value('parent_id', isset($request_type->request_type) ? $request_type->request_type : 'Parent Id*'));
    }                    
?>
</div>
```

my controller

```
public function create()
{

    $this->auth->restrict($this->permissionCreate);
    $data['reqt'] = $this->db->get('request_type')->result();
    Template::set('request_type');

    if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
        if ($insert_id = $this->save_request_type()) {
            log_activity($this->auth->user_id(), lang('request_type_act_create_record') . ': ' . $insert_id . ' : ' . $this->input->ip_address(), 'request_type');
            Template::set_message(lang('request_type_create_success'), 'success');

            redirect(SITE_AREA . '/settings/request_type');
        }

        // Not validation error
        if ( ! empty($this->request_type_model->error)) {
            Template::set_message(lang('request_type_create_failure') . $this->request_type_model->error, 'error');
        }
    }

    Template::set('toolbar_title', lang('request_type_action_create'));

    Template::render();
}
/**
 * Allows editing of Request Type data.
 *
 * @return void
```

Comment: Please ALWAYS show ALL the error message

Comment: A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1366

Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'parent_id' at row 1

INSERT INTO `cli_request_type` (`request_type`, `parent_id`, `created_on`, `created_by`) VALUES ('Software', '', '2019-03-13 10:35:54', 1)

Filename: C:/Xamppi/htdocs/clihelpdesk/bonfire/core/BF_Model.php

Line Number: 482

Comment: according to your select image please refer this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55003622/show-categories-side-by-side-using-codeigniter]

Comment: `Incorrect integer value` means your table expects `parent_id` to be an integer  (most likely it has `INT` for data type). An empty value (which is not the same as a `NULL` value) is not an integer. If you need to insert a null value, you need to be explicit in your model to insert a null value (`$this->db->set('parent_id', null, false);` for example)

Comment: @M.Hemant the example is almost the same as what I did, and the subid has a value of 0, only one is in flowers, I have more than one data that has a subid value of 0, Thanks :)

Comment: @JavierLarroulet its not working

Comment: what i'm saying here is that you are traying to insert a empty string in a integer column 
. first you can't insert a string in a integer column , second linnked to your title you wanna insert a null into a id , considere that is not good if it's possible 
my advice is to create a column with true or false named isHasParent , or even create a default parent while inserting the id of the default in your request .

Answer (score 0):

but can it make null values more than one, in integer data types?